# Limit Magento PHP query to last 30 minutes

Tags: php, magento, zend-db

I have tried filtering this many ways and am stuck any help is appreciated.
updated_at comes out as:
2014-08-29 16:59:43

Currently getting the error:
DATEADD does not exist' in /chroot/home/campdev/dev8.campsaver.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

```
    $res = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); $ordersTable = $res->getTableName('sales/order');
    $db = $res->getConnection('sales_read'); 
    $lastEntityId = 0; $sql = new Varien_Db_Select($db);
    if ($lastOrder) { $lastEntityId = self::getOrderEntityId($db, $sql, $lastDate, $lastOrder); }
    $sql = $db->select()
              ->from($ordersTable, 'entity_id')
              ->where('store_id=?', self::$_storeId, Zend_Db::INT_TYPE)
              ->where('updated_at < DATEADD(minute, -, GETDATE())')
              ->where("entity_id > $lastEntityId")
              ->limit($batchsize, $startnum);
    if (self::$_debug) { echo "Executing SQL: $sql\r\n"; }
    $ordRows = $db->fetchAll($sql);
```

Comment: RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html  It's `DATE_ADD`

Comment: Touche. I had been using mssql for weeks threw me off.